# Singleton object that manages its own boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost, singleton

**Singleton.h**

```
class Singleton{
public:
 static Singleton &getInstance() {
      static Singleton instance;
      return instance;
 }
 void start();
 void run();
 void join();

private:
 Singleton();
 int a;
 boost::thread thread;
};
```

**Singleton.cpp**

```
Singleton()::Singleton:a(0){}
void Singleton::run(){ a=1; }
void Singleton::start(){ thread = boost::thread(&Singleton::run, this, NULL); }
void Singleton::join(){ thread.join(); }
```

**main.cpp**

```
Singleton::getInstance().start();
Singleton::getInstance().join();
```

The error I get is

> /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void
>   boost::_bi::list2::operator()(boost::_bi::type, F&, A&,
>   int) [with F = void (Singleton::*)(); A = boost::_bi::list0; A1 =
>   boost::_bi::value; A2 = boost::_bi::value]’:
>   /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:59:   required from
>   ‘boost::_bi::bind_t::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t::operator()() [with R = void; F = void (Singleton::*)(); L =
>   boost::_bi::list2, boost::_bi::value >; boost::_bi::bind_t::result_type = void]’
>   /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:117:17:   required from
>   ‘void boost::detail::thread_data::run() [with F =
>   boost::_bi::bind_t, boost::_bi::value > >]’ Singleton.cpp:4:1:   required
>   from here

I'm stuck and not sure what to do here,
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you giving `run` a `NULL` ?

Comment: This is tagged C++11, so I'm curious as to why you aren't using those features in place of boost?

Comment: `Singleton():a(0){}`, did you mean to write `Singleton::Singleton():a(0){}` or is that how it actually looks?

Comment: Singleton::Singleton:a(0){}

Comment: Dieter Lücking You are correct, That solved it, but run doesn't have parameters? Isn't the third parameter of boost::thread with this signature is parameter passed to run?

Comment: @DieterLücking, for some reason I get `Parameter type mismatch: Types 'const boost::thread::attributes' and void (*)() are not compatible` (in editor not in compilation) when using only two parameters in boost::thread, thats why I added NULL in the third parameter of boost::thread.

Comment: Hence a false error of a smart editor: '"in editor not in compilation" - ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your post is tagged <kbd>C++11</kbd>, I've taken the liberty of using its features. I've implemented your code without issue:

```
#include <thread>

class Singleton{
public:
   static Singleton &getInstance() 
   {
      static Singleton instance;
      return instance;
   }

   void start()
   {
      thread = std::thread(
         [this]() // lambda to call internal run method
         {
             run();
         });
   }

   void run()
   {
      a=1;
   }

   void join()
   {
      thread.join();
   }


private:
   Singleton() = default;
   int a = 0;
   std::thread thread;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d169ab9111fb4731)

Notice I use `std::thread`, defaulted constructor, a lambda, and an in-class member initializer.

Comment: sorry, I need boost solution, removed C++11 from tags.

Comment: @Koten: I'm curious as to why it was tagged C++11 in the first place. Are you compiling  with a C++11 compiler, but just cannot use `std::thread`? Anyhow, did you see my latest comment on the OP? Also, since `std::thread` is basically the same as `boost::thread`, if you're compiling with a C++11 compatible compiler, you should be able to do everything I did, except use a `boost::thread` instead of a `std::thread`

Comment: I'm using std with boost so I'm compiling with -std=c++11